# How to send the data finded in the controller to a view?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-jdbc

I try to do a java web application using:
SpringBoot
Mysql
JDBC
Design pattern: MVC, DAO
And Thymeleaf
I think i understood than:
I must create a class for every Entity  and a DAO classe who use the annotation @Repository:
Diabetic.java(Entity):

```
    public class Diabetic {

    private int id_diabetic;
    private int id_doctor;
    private String name;
    private String firstname;
    private Date birthdate;
    private String mail;
    private String password;
    private String phone;
    private String emergencyContact;
    private String address;

    public Diabetic() {
    }

    public Diabetic(int id_diabetic, int id_doctor, String name, String firstname, Date birthdate,
                    String mail, String password, String phone, String emergencyContact, String address) {
        this.id_diabetic = id_diabetic;
        this.id_doctor = id_doctor;
        this.name = name;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.password = password;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.emergencyContact = emergencyContact;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getId_diabetic() {
        return id_diabetic;
    }

    public void setId_diabetic(int id_diabetic) {
        this.id_diabetic = id_diabetic;
    }

    public int getId_doctor() {
        return id_doctor;
    }

    public void setId_doctor(int id_doctor) {
        this.id_doctor = id_doctor;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public Date getBirthdate() {
        return birthdate;
    }

    public void setBirthdate(Date birthdate) {
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmergencyContact() {
        return emergencyContact;
    }

    public void setEmergencyContact(String emergencyContact) {
        this.emergencyContact = emergencyContact;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

DiabeticDAO.java:

```
@Repository
public class DiabeticDAO {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private SimpleJdbcInsert simpleJdbcInsert;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource){
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        this.simpleJdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName("diabetic")
                .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id_diabetic");
    }

    public Diabetic getDiabById(int id){
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from Diabetic where id_diabetic=?", new DiabeticRowMapper(),id);
    }

    public List<Diabetic> getAllDiab(){
        return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from Diabetic",new DiabeticRowMapper());

    }

    private final class DiabeticRowMapper implements RowMapper<Diabetic> {
        @Override
        public Diabetic mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException{
            Diabetic diabetic = new Diabetic();
            diabetic.setId_diabetic(rs.getInt("id_diabetic"));
            diabetic.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            diabetic.setFirstname(rs.getString("firstname"));
            diabetic.setBirthdate(rs.getDate("birthdate"));
            diabetic.setMail(rs.getString("mail"));
            diabetic.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
            diabetic.setPhone(rs.getString("phone"));
            diabetic.setEmergencyContact(rs.getString("emergencyContact"));
            diabetic.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
            return diabetic;
        }

    }
}
```

And create a controller like this where I use the method from the DAO:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String firstPage(){
        return"firstPage";
    }

    @GetMapping("/authentification")
    public String auth(){
        DiabeticDAO diaDao = new DiabeticDAO();
        List<Diabetic> listDia = diaDao.getAllDiab();
        return"loggin";
    }
```

What i don't understand:

1. How to do a link in a view(html) to go to a controller ?
2. How to send the data finded in the controller to a view for displaying them ?

Sorry if my questions seems strange but it's the first time i ask for help on here and english is not my first language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don´t have to link a controller in the view.
The connection is handled trough the URL calls of the controller.

I´m taking examples from this introduction:
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html

You can use several methods to add data to the view.

**1. Option:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "message", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String messages(Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("messages", messageRepository.findAll());
   return "message/list";
}
```

In this method we put "Model model" as a parameter to the method. You can now fill the model with some data.

**2. Option:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "message", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView messages() {
   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("message/list");
   mav.addObject("messages", messageRepository.findAll());
   return mav;
}
```

In this method we create a ModelAndView object, setting the url which should be called and fill it with data. Again the data is called "messages". The return value is the created object.

**Access data in view:**

After you implemented one of the two options, you can access the data like this:

```
<tr th:each="message : ${messages}">
   <td th:text="${message.id}">1</td>
   <td><a href="#" th:text="${message.title}">Title ...</a></td>
   <td th:text="${message.text}">Text ...</td>
</tr>
```

**Let´s try to implement it into your current code:**

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String firstPage(){
        return"firstPage";
    }

    @GetMapping("/authentification")
    public String auth(Model model){
        DiabeticDAO diaDao = new DiabeticDAO();
        List<Diabetic> listDia = diaDao.getAllDiab();
        model.addAttribute("listdia", listDia);
        return"loggin";
    }
}
```

Now you can access the data in your view:

```
<tr th:each="dia: ${listdia}">
   <td th:text="${dia.id_diabetic}">1</td>
   <td><a href="#" th:text="${dia.name}">Name</a></td>
   <td th:text="${dia.firstname}">Firstname</td>
</tr>
```